# AFNetworking upload task with POST parameters

Tags: ios, cocoa, afnetworking-2

I'm wondering how to use AFNetworking to make a POST request with a file, a few parameters and progress report of the upload.

AFURLSessionManager's [uploadTaskWithRequest:fromFile:progress:completionHandler](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.2/Classes/AFURLSessionManager.html#//api/name/uploadTaskWithRequest%3afromFile%3aprogress%3acompletionHandler%3a) works for POST upload with progress, but I cannot figure out how to add the POST parameters.

I've also looked into AFHTTPSessionManager's [POST:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:success:failure:](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.2/Classes/AFHTTPSessionManager.html#//api/name/POST%3aparameters%3aconstructingBodyWithBlock%3asuccess%3afailure%3a), but that doesn't appear to be able to report upload progress.

How do I get the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at using a combination of `uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:progress:completionHandler:` and `multipartFormRequestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:`.